# android sdk sms simplecursoradapter and getting contact name

Tags: android, sdk, cursor, sms

I have been racking my brain over various posts where it shows how to get the contact name but as this appears to be coming from another internal database how can I include this in the existing cursor to apply to the simplecursoradapter ?

so far I have found and read these posts:

[How to get contact name for sms conversations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453916/how-to-get-contact-name-for-sms-conversations)

[How to get contact name when receiving SMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16074617/how-to-get-contact-name-when-receiving-sms)

[Why are my contact photos not displaying in listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029475/why-are-my-contact-photos-not-displaying-in-listview)

[How do i get the SMS Sender Contact (Person) saved name using "content://sms/inbox"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765795/how-do-i-get-the-sms-sender-contact-person-saved-name-using-content-sms-inb)

And although they show how to get the contact name I am then trying to include this in the existing code which gets the sms inbox and messages

Thanks

Tim

Answer (score 0):

Sorted this now - had a programming block as I had not been on Android for a while and remember that a custom simplecursoradapter will do this